# getting first level children?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Can anyone help me with the problem of getting first level children using LINQ?

Gallery picker picks one folder, and I need to fetch it's first level children.
It's should be something like this for a start, but I'm totally new to LINQ and whatever I tried I keep returng me an error.

```
List <"Media"> libraryItems = MediaHelper.GetChildrenMedia(this.CurrentContent.GalleryPicker.Value);
```

This list of media items I should forward to repeater.

Comment: Aaand, what does the error say..?

Comment: You should at least show `GetChildrenMedia`, otherwise we can't see the problem.

Comment: var libraryItems = maybe this

Comment: where is the linq expression in your code?

Comment: This is a good site for linq examples http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: `List<"Media">` will not work. Maybe you meant `List<Media>`. Also, I guess noone here knows what `GetChildrenMedia` is or how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is this:

```
List<"Media">
```

You don't need quotes around the type, it should be:

```
List<Media>
```

Now, your `GetChildrenMedia` should look something like this (I'm assuming hierarchy and columns here, but you get the general idea):

```
List<Media> libraryItems = MediaHelper.GetChildrenMedia(this.CurrentContent.GalleryPicker.Value);

public List<Media> GetChildrenMedia(Gallery gallery)
{
    List<Media> output = repository.Media
        .Where(m => m.GalleryId == gallery.Id)
        .ToList();

    return output;
}
```